# How to use pipeline-multibranch-defaults-plugin in mutilbranch-pipeline job？

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins version '2.414.1', plguin 'Pipeline: Multibranch with defaults'
I created the Groovy file with the id 'test' in the 'Managed files' under the 'system configuration' of Jenkins, and then used it in a multi-branch pipeline job,as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C7Dt.jpg)
it works fine.

but I created it in 'Config Files' under the multi-branch pipeline job, and configure it in the job; It prompts an error when running:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default Jenkinsfile not found. Check configuration.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.multibranch.defaults.DefaultsBinder.create(DefaultsBinder.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:311)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't know what causes this.

Very much looking forward to the answer.